# Pandas one-liner to group all values together that constitute under a threshold of the total volume

Tags: python, pandas, counter, frequency, frequency-analysis

I have a dataframe `df` which contains a column named `object_name`. The frequency distribution of the values contained in `object_name` is as follows:

[image]

What I want is to rename as `misc` or `other` all the values in the column whose presence is less than, say, 5% of the whole column. So, for example, if the length of the dataframe is 50,000 rows, then I want all values in `object_name` to be renamed to `other` or `misc` which have under 2500 occurrences. In the above example, that would mean the first 5 values would remain as is, and the rest of the values are renamed to `other` or `misc`.

I can probably do that in a convoluted way with one or more for loops. But I wonder if there can be a one-liner to do this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit long for a one-liner, but it should do the job.

It gets the normalized `value_counts` of each item, which is its frequency. Filters to only keep ones with a frequency `<0.05` and then creates a mask for the original dataframe of values from that list. We select those items, and change them to equal `other`.

```
df.loc[df.object_name.isin(df.object_name.value_counts(normalize=True)[lambda x: x<0.05].index), 'object_name'] = 'other'
```